# A mutation of the Collatz disease

Tags: nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, collatz-conjecture

Given $k \in \mathbb N$, we define $f_k: \mathbb N \longrightarrow \mathbb N$ by

$$ f_k(x) = \begin{cases} \,\quad\dfrac{x}2 &\text{ if } x \text{ is even} \\\\ \dfrac{3x+3^k}{2} & \text{ if } x \text{ is odd} \end{cases} $$

For $k=0$, we have the function of the infamous Collatz conjecture.

*Does there exist for some $k\geq 0$ a strictly positive natural integer $N_k$ whose iterates under $f_k$ do not end up in the
trivial cycle $\lbrace 3^k,2\cdot 3^k\rbrace$ of $f_k$?*

Comment: This is essentially the usual collatz conjecture for rationals whose denominator is a power of three. I dont know the answer to this question, but I suggest checking out the references in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Iterating_on_rationals_with_odd_denominators.

Comment: At least the section about parity cycles seem to imply that the Collatz sequence for numbers whose denominator is a power of three either is unbounded or, if it becomes periodic, it always ends up in the trivial cycle above.

Comment: EDIT: oops I missed that the denominator $2^n-3^m$ can be $\pm 1$. Are there only finitely many solutions for $m,n$ for this equation. If so, there should be only finitely many Collatz-cycles in the integers and the section in wikipedia should give a way to list them all. Maybe the 1,4,2 -cycle is the only positive one.

Comment: Sorry even that is not true. Maybe the denominator is not $\pm 1$, but the numerator is divisible by it. Then we would still get an integral cycle and these are not covered by my previous comment.

Comment: @HenrikRüping Thanks for your pertinent comments. I should have read the Wikipedia article before posting.

Comment: Is the $2$ in $\dfrac{3x+3^k}{2}$ a typo?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo No, the 2 is not a typo: $(3x+3^k)$ is always even for odd $x$, it is therefore natural to divide it by $2$ immediately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe it is worth to write my comments into an answer:

1. The question is equivalent to asking whether all elements of the form $n/3^k$ end up in the collatz cycle.
2. It is still an open question whether there is an integer $n$ where the collatz iterates go to infinity
3. It is still an open question whether there are other integral positive Collatz cycles
4. Iterating with starting value $n/3^k$ for some $k$ and $n\neq 0$, we always end up with an integer after finitely many steps. Each $x\mapsto 3x+1$ decreases the exponent of $3$ in the denominator by one.  So the question is equivalent to asking whether the conjectures 2,3 hold.

Comment: One can say a little more.  All the positive elements of $\Bbb Z[\frac16]$ converge, and in fact one can write an inequality within the negative integers which weighs up the 2-adic and 3-adic values of any given dyadic/ternary rational and tells you whether or not its orbit is eventually positive.

Comment: sorry but I have no idea how to extend the collatz iteration to rationals with denominator divisible by two. Can you explain what you mean by that ?

Comment: Sorry a number of ways, all are essentially equivalent to "multiply by two until odd" but the broadest is the extension to $\Bbb Q_2$ you get if you consider the function $c(x)=3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}$ then let $c^n(x)$ indicate the nth composition. Then let $p(x):\Bbb Q_2\to\{0,1\}$ indicate $x\pmod2$. Then let $T(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty p(c^n(x))$.  In this case $T$ is a 2-adic (isometric) homeomorphism and the Collatz conjecture asks if $T(\Bbb Z[\frac16]^+\setminus\{\frac13\})\subset \frac13\Bbb N$

Comment: Sorry, that was wrong. It should have been $p(x)=2^{\nu_2(x)}$ then $T=\sum_{k=0}^\infty p(c^n(x))$

Comment: I've answered a question in MSE where I show, that the iteration in question is exactly equivalent to the 3x+1 iteration, and that no cycles other than in 3x+1 iteration can occur. I could copy that answer here, or see at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4728332/1714 The last two paragraphs focus the question here.

Answer (score 0):

*commen: this is a copy of my MSE-answer which I [linked to](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4728332/1714) by the other comment. Because of the existent discussion in the comments here I thought today, it would be convenient to have it explicitely here. The explicite answer for the case here is then the **last sentence** after the whole derivation*

---

---

[...]

Looking at the more general question for $3x+r$ might simplify the understanding as well for the the special case where $r=3$ or even $r=3^k$.

**Preliminaries**
The Syracuse-notation for the Collatz-transformation might be written in this form for odd positive elements $a_k$ and positive integer parameters $A_k$ in the exponents:
$$ T_{3,1}:= \qquad  a_{k+1} = {3a_k+ 1\over 2^{A_k}}  \tag {1.1} $$
Iterating this to $N$ steps can be written as
$$ a_{k+N} = { 3^N  \over 2^S } a_k + { 3^{N-1} + 3^{N-2} 2^{A_1} + 3^{N-3} 2^{A_1+A_2} + \cdots 2^{A_1 + ...+ A_{N-1} }   \over 2^S} \tag {1.2}
$$
where here (and always in the following) I denote $S = \sum_{k=1}^N A_k$.

I find it useful to introduce a notation for the long numerator in eq 1.2 :
$$ \text{using } \qquad E_{N,S} = [A_1,A_2,...,A_k,...,A_N] \qquad \text{ then } \\
Q(E_{N,S}) =  3^{N-1} + 3^{N-2} 2^{A_1} + 3^{N-3} 2^{A_1+A_2} + \cdots 2^{A_1 + ... +A_{N-1} } \tag {1.3}
$$
We have then the expression for an $N$-step iteration from some $a_1$ to $a_{N+1}$ in a much shorter form as
$$ T_{3,1}^{\circ N}:= \qquad a_{1+N} = { 3^N  \over 2^S } a_1 + { Q(E_{N,S}) \over 2^S} \tag {1.4}
$$
and the expression for the first element $a_1$ in a cycle *(when $a_1 = a_{N+1}$)* of $N$ (odd) steps and $S$ divisions by $2$,  with some exponent vector of $A_k$'s (use the symbol $E_{N,S}$ for its representation) by
$$   a_1 = {Q(E_{N,S}) \over 2^S - 3^N } \tag {1.5}
$$

---

**Derivations** Now for the generalization $r$ of the summand in eq 1.1
$$ T_{3,r}:= \qquad a_{k+1} = {3a_k+ r\over 2^{A_k}}  \tag {2.1} $$
it comes out that the function $Q()$ is not affected by this generalization and only eq 1.4 changes minimally:
$$ a_{1+N} = { 3^N  \over 2^S } a_1 + {r \cdot Q(E_{N,S}) \over 2^S} \tag {2.4}
$$
and as well for the cycle-formula:
$$   a_1 = { r \cdot Q(E_{N,S}) \over 2^S - 3^N } \tag {2.5}
$$

---

From eq 2.4 we see the equivalence of the $T_{3,r}()$-transformation with the original Syracuse if we replace the $a_k$ by $r \cdot b_k$. We get then
$$ r \cdot b_{1+N} = { 3^N  \over 2^S } r \cdot b_1 + {r \cdot Q(E_{N,S}) \over 2^S} \tag {3.1a}
$$
and cancelling the factor $r$ we get
$$  b_{1+N} = { 3^N  \over 2^S }  b_1 + { Q(E_{N,S}) \over 2^S} \tag {3.1b}
$$
which is simply the Syracuse-formulation on the variables $b_k$.
For instance for $a_1=15 = 3 \cdot 5$ we have with $r=3$ the obvious equivalence
$$   T_{3,3}:  3\cdot 1 = {(3 \cdot 5) \cdot 3+3 \over 2^4 } \\
 \sim T_{3,1}: 1 \cdot 1 = {(1 \cdot 5) \cdot 3+1 \over 2^4 }  \tag {3.2a}
  $$
as well as after allowance of fractional values for the $T_{3,1}$-Syracuse transformation:
$$   T_{3,3}:  3 = { 7\cdot 3+3 \over 2^3 } \\
 \sim T_{3,1}: 1=(3/3) = {(7/3) \cdot 3+1 \over 2^3 }  \tag {3.2b}
  $$

---

Aside of this instructive representation of equivalency between $T_{3,r}$ and $T_{3,1}$ there occurs here first time the problem of dealing with fractional values in the Collatz-problem. It is of course not a big problem to extend the domain for the Collatz-conjecture to *fractional* values, but once we allow fractional values in the $a_k$ then we shall as well introduce the possibilities of non-integer elements on cycles.

The Collatz-problem is then, more explicitely: "there is no cycle ***in integral values*** $a_k>0$ other than $a_k=1$" - but on fractional values cycles might occur!

We start at the cycle-equation eq 2.5:
$$   a_1 = { r \cdot Q(E_{N,S}) \over 2^S - 3^N } \tag {4.1}
$$
Let us assume, there are no non-trivial cycles for the Collatz-problem, operationalized by the $T_{3,1}$-definition eq 1.1 . Once allowing fractional values we can only say: no ***integer-valued*** cycles. It implies, that, given some $N$ and from this $S$, the primefactors in the denominator cannot all be cancelled by the function $Q(E_{N,S})$ in the numerator.
Let's see one example. Assume $N=3$ and $S=5$. Then for $T_{3,1}$ we get
$$ a_1  = { 1 \cdot Q(E_{N,S}) \over 32 - 27 } = { Q([A_1,A_2,A_3]) \over 5 } \tag {4.2} $$
and no configuration $\small [A_1,A_2,A_3]$ with $\small A_1+A_2+A_3=S=5$ produces a primefactor $5$ in the numerator and so we stay with a fractional result for $a_1$.
But if we use $r=5$ and thus the transformation $T_{3,5}$ we get
$$ a_1  = { 5 \cdot Q(E_{N,S}) \over 32 - 27 } = { 5 \cdot Q([A_1,A_2,A_3]) \over 5 } = Q([A_1,A_2,A_3]) \tag {4.3} $$
and the following solutions are all integral in $a_k$:
$$ a_1=Q([1,1,3]) \qquad a_2=Q([1,3,1]) \qquad a_3=Q([3,1,1])  \\
 a_1=Q([1,2,2] \qquad a_2=Q([2,2,1]) \qquad a_3=Q([2,1,2])  \tag {4.4}
  $$
where we have two solutions for $a_1$, each with 3 needed rotations each.

Another example: for the 5-odd-step-cycle  $N=5$ from where $S=8$ we have in the denominator $2^8 - 3^5=13$ and thus $r=13$ allows one or more cycles.
By the possible combinations of the exponents $A_k$ (resp. rotations) we find a couple of cycles already mentioned elsewhere in MSE
$$\small \begin{array} {llll}
a_1=Q([1,1,1,1,4]) & a_2=Q([1,1,1,4,1]) & a_3=Q([1,1,4,1,1]) & \ldots \phantom{\vdots} \\
a_1=Q([1,1,1,2,3]) & a_2=Q([1,1,2,3,1]) & a_3=Q([1,2,3,1,1]) & \ldots \phantom{\vdots}  \\
a_1=Q([1,1,2,2,2]) & a_2=Q([1,2,2,2,1]) & a_3=Q([2,2,2,1,1]) & \ldots \phantom{\vdots}  \\
a_1 = \; \vdots       &  a_2 = \; \vdots & a_3 = \; \vdots & \ldots \\
\end{array} \tag {4.5}
$$
*(giving $7$ cycles (and their rotations) all with $(N,S)=(5,8)$ )*

---

From this we have now a simple recipe to find some $r$ which allows integer cycles for any $N$ *(and its according $S$ where $S=\small \lceil N \cdot \log_2(3) \rceil$)* : simply use some $r$ which cancels the primefactors in the denominator $\small 2^S-3^N$ by the factors of $r \cdot \small Q(E_{N,S})$.

---

This last consideration implies as well one more property: since in the denominator there will never occur a primefactor $3$ no $r=3^k$ can have any effect on the cancelling property and any $r=3^k$ shall have no more nontrivial cycles than the original Collatz-transformation $T_{3,1}$ (thus as far as we know: no nontrivial cycles at all).